# Crystal report dynamic formula name

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Here is what I have.  I have 15 unique formulas named Week1, Week2, ... Week15.  I would like to be able to take a parameter name, MYCount, and use that to loop through the records and sum them.  So if MyCount is equal to 3, the loop would sum Week1 + Week2 + Week3.  I know how to create a loop, but I cannot figure out how to build the formula name dynamically. Here is what I have so far: (I am using Crystal Xi)

```
 Whileprintingrecords;
 local NumberVar i := {?MyCount}
 For i := 1 To (MyCount-1) Do (
    i = {@Week & "i"} + i
 );
 x
```

Comment: Can you post the logic for one of the Week formulae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be over complicating. Why not just do:

```
Local numbervar x := 0;
If param > 0 then
 X := x + week1;
If param > 1 then
 X := x + week;
And so on...
 X;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The formula would get really large.  I will eventually have about 100 weeks.  I was hoping to avoid listing them all out since I will have a few different formulas doing these kind of sums.

Comment: Thank you for this, I finally get what you mean.  Could not see the forest between the trees... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly what you are trying to do, but you may want to consider another approach.

Create a formula that will segment a field based on a date field's week number:

```
//{@amount}
// adjust firstDayOfWeek and firstDayOfYear parameters to match your organization's
// definition of a week
If DatePart("ww", {table.dateField})<={?Week} Then
  {table.amount}
```

Insert a summarized field on the formula field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your `@Weekn` formula fields so that you can summarise by date across the page, then have you considered using Crystal's [Crosstab](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Crystal_Reports_XI.asp?Page=10_1) functionality instead?

Comment: UNfortunately I cannot do that.  I need to only sum the certain weeks.  I was really hoping I could build a formula name with a varible.

Comment: @Mike: You could achieve that by either selecting only the relevant weeks (if you don't need the other weeks at all) or setting up a formula to hold the value for the relevant weeks (if you need to display but not sum the other weeks).